# What is the "participation" tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags

Over the last few days, I've seen lots of questions tagged with [participation](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/participation), but I don't really understand the purpose of the tag.  What does it mean when a question is tagged "participation"?  What is the difference between a "participation" and a "non-participation" question?  Why do we need to categorize questions this way?

Comment: Had a similar thought, but decided to hold off and go with it. If we're going this route, I would call the tag `eligibility` as questions with this tag have been regards to if and/or who can participate based on stipulation, eligibility, etc.

Comment: To address wax eagle's answer, it would be useful to distinguish fan questions with those who are actually participating in the sport...as we welcome both with open arms. **In theory**, this sounds great. **In current practice**, see my comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, this tag should be used for questions about *the participation in* sport.

So questions about how to become an NFL player (Ed's recent one about the draft), questions about sports equipment etc.

This is (in theory) to distinguish player questions from fan questions.